# Terribly slow performance of TCPClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcpclient

For learning purposes (I want to get firm grasp on HTTP internals) I'm writing simple HTTP server, which would parse request according to [rfc7230-7235](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230) and proxy it to my simple backend server.

I'm not aspiring to beat any existing solution, but apparently `TCPClient` is working very slow for some reason. Direct call to my backend would take in worse scenario just 20ms, when calling it using my simple server would take at least 200ms, which is awful.

Parsing aside, which takes mostly insignificant toll on response time, this is minimal code which would take response and send it as is to backend:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Logger.Info("Start listener.");
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPEndPoint.Parse("0.0.0.0:5000"));
    listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

        using var c_stream = client.GetStream();

        // read request
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        int i;
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        while ((i = await c_stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024)) != 0)
        {
            await ms.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, i);
            if (i < 1024) break;
        }

        // write whole request as-is to backend
        using var backend = new TcpClient();
        await backend.ConnectAsync(IPEndPoint.Parse("172.21.215.119:3000"));
        var b_stream = backend.GetStream();

        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.WriteTo(b_stream);
        await b_stream.FlushAsync();

        // read output from backend to memory
        ms.Position = 0;
        while ((i = await b_stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024)) != 0)
        {
            await ms.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, i);
            if (i < 1024) break;
        }

        // send back to fuckin client
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.WriteTo(c_stream);
        await c_stream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is important, but my environment looks like that:

1. I'm working on windows 10 machine with WSL 2.
2. Backend is setup on WSL (ubuntu). It's just pet shop on nestjs.
3. Backend calls mongodb, which is setup in docker environment (also WSL).

In my minimal code example, each request takes 200-250ms, at least on my machine. It isn't that much different from how my actual code works. The biggest difference might be, that I'm spamming tasks for each request and I have a lot of validation related to RFC requirements.

If there are some good resources on how to use TCPClient (or Sockets if necessary) correctly, then I would gladly take it.

Comment: How large are backend responses? Also, is there a reason to first read to memory and only then rewrite everything back to the client?

Comment: Outside your application, it might be worthwhile getting some baseline network stats, do a ping or tracert between the ip's you're using. There might be something causing a delay in the way it's routing traffic, unlikely but always best to check. 2nd It could be the .Net garbage collector. Try not disposing of any instances and see if it makes a difference. I don't see any timing code here do I'm not sure how you're measuring the time but it might be worth measuring sections of your code independently to help identify the slowest section which will give you a place to focus on.

Comment: @WiktorZychla backend responses are usually small JSON's. It's less than 1MB. This example is pretty dumb to be honest, in my real scenario I'm reading data to buffers.

Comment: @NicholasBergesen thanks for answer, seems like a good start. Maybe garbage collection might be a thing here, so I'll check which parts of code are the most time consuming. Then I'll try to reuse some buffers to check if times change at all.

About timing. I just used HTTP client (insomnia) at the end which showed me response time of each query. Not too reliable, but easy :) I'll go back with some real measurements.

Comment: You are copying the whole request into memory, then writing it back out again. Why don't you just feed it straight through and avoid the memorystream `await c_stream.CopyToAsync(b_stream); await b_stream.CopyToAsync(c_stream);`

Comment: @Charlieface okay, that's on me. I would gladly do it as you said, but it's just my minimal working example which by using ```MemoryStream``` emulates parsing of data which needs to be done in memory anyway. That doesn't change the fact, that whole request is taking tenfold of what the same, direct request to backend would take.

Comment: Considering the amount of time a TLS Hello can take, it's not entirely surprising. Perhaps you can keep a connection open by using Keep-Alive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, apparently answer is quite... Disturbing...

I solved this issue by changing call to `http://localhost:port` to `http://127.0.0.1:port`.

Now even my dumb proxy implementation in this example, minimal code takes few milliseconds to run.

Seems like there is some kind of issue with localhost resolution on windows which honestly is beyond me. Apparently it's not only my problem, some user on reddit ([post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/rj5nf3/comment/hp2khes/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)) that helped me, had the same issue when tried to run code similar to mine.

Comment: thanks so much. Have been debugging this for 10 hours

Comment: Glad to be helpful here @CasperKuethe I have been struggling with this problem for few days. It's really terrible networking issue and one that's really surprising and not at all documented.